# Order a vector in function to another vector

Tags: r

```r
>nuevos<-(exam[411:510,1])

>  [,1]
401 -0.325087210
402  0.576824342
403  0.314110438
404 -0.710141482
405  0.079179458
406  0.876819478
407 -0.563755647
408 -0.024573542
409  0.072860869
410  0.141759722
411  0.645346837
412 -0.178754696
413 -0.745086021
414  0.741761201
415  1.537360962
416  0.478560270
417 -0.721503050
418 -0.136435690
419 -0.264058207
420  1.851815905
421  0.854542022
422  0.055184071
423  0.214454147
424 -0.374941314
425  0.268580192
426  0.458531169
427  0.440158449
428 -1.539627467
429 -0.146698388
430 -0.174844929
```

This is my data, it's a matrix. The first column is the ID and the second column is the X value. I want to select 10 ID. In the 10 selected, 5 should be from unpair number ID, and the other 5 should be from ood number ID. The 10 ID selection should be in function from the X value (the most negative value is the best). I want to have something like this:

```r
ID       X
428 -1.539627467
413 -0.745086021
....
```

I tried to use `sort(data[data%%2==1])[1:5]` but I don't understand how can I extract the column ID from the dataset, because this is a result from a linear model, so R give me the positions but I want to work with this positions and the X value. Please, help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a `dput` of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the first "column" are the rownames of the matrix.
Since the objects in your question have differing names, it's not entirely clear to me if the following works like that.

So I would do something like this:

```r
df=data.frame(ID=rownames(exam),X=exam[,1])
```

Otherwise please post the output of `dput(exam)` or `dput(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think you want to do, here's a working example, given the following data frame:

```
# generate random input data
data <- data.frame(ID=1:20, X=rnorm(20))
```

Tidyverse offers the cleanest solution:

```
require(tidyverse)
data %>%
  arrange(X)
```

will sort in ascending order according to column x. Check the [documentation for arrange](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) for further details; you can do more complex things such as sorting by group, sorting on multiple columns (ie, specify a first column, and break ties based on successively sorted columns, etc). So what I would recommend would be to put your data into a data frame first:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=rownames(nuevos), X=nuevos[,1])
```

where you could substitute ID with whatever you want and then do the above. Add a `dput` of `nuevos` for more specific feedback. Note there are a million ways under the sun to do this not involving tidyverse (ie, sort as you mentioned, for instance); tidyverse just tends to make for the cleanest, simplest mechanism in my opinion (since it is plug and play with many other useful things, like `ggplot`, `dplyr`, etc) and is really a great way of thinking to get accustomed to for working with data frames, such as this.